# How to collapse/expand only regions by keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've found **Quick Launch** has `CollapseRegions` and `ExpandRegions` which  functionality is actually what I need.

But I would like it to be toggled by key in like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd> instead of using Quick Launch like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> > CollapseRegions > <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017  : 
Go to Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advance -> activate 'Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions'

Explicitly to collapse all using  Ctrl+M+O and for expand use Ctrl+M+X.

Comment: Is there any way to collapse/expand `only regions`?

Comment: Means method are not?

Comment: I mean that I would like to collapse/expand only regions and do not collapse/expand others like namespace, class, function at the same time. Ctrl+M+O isn't what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Namespaces will also collapse/expand using this command.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, `CollapseRegions` and `ExpandRegions` can do  collapse/expand only regions. The functionality is what I need but I need they to be as keyboard shortcut like Ctrl+M, J instead of keying in Ctrl+Q > coll > enter.

Comment: Yes above short cut worked same like ctrl+Q > coll > enter. If you deselect above mentioned checkbox.

Comment: If I uncheck that checkbox, it will only collapse/expand the other parts and regions won't be collapsed/expanded.
If I check that checkbox, it will collapse/expand all of the parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177314/discussion-between-srusti-thakkar-and-terry-wei).